# regression with constraints on weights python

Tags: python, optimization, regression, constraints

I want to do a regression. the y series is provided, so does a dataframe(df) with columns x1,x2,x3...,xn. I would like to have the regression as follows: y=b0+b1x1+b2x2+b3x3+...+bnxn where bi(i=1,2,3...,n) is in (0,1) and the sum of b1+b2+b3+...bn<=1

I was told to use scipy.optimize.minimize, but reading through the guidance(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize), I still had no clue how to write the code. Thanks in advance!